# How to avoid memory issues when creating a mosaic of raster tiles using terra?

Tags: terra

I have a list containing 375 raster tiles that I would like to mosaic into one raster:

```
filelist_lc <- list.files("Northern_Land_Cover_2000/")
lc_2000_tiles <- lapply(filelist_lc, rast)

> lc_2000_tiles[[1]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4962, 5049, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 1614258, 1765728, 8094905, 8243765  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : LCC         E008 
source      : 014M.tif 
name        : 014M 

lc_2000_tiles[[2]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4791, 4747, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 1462288, 1604698, 8381835, 8525565  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : LCC         E008 
source      : 015L.tif 
name        : 015L 

....
```

I was trying to figure out a way to use mosaic them. This was the solution I came up with. However, after 7 tiles are combined, the computer runs out of disk space.

```
Error: [merge] internal error: insufficient disk space (perhaps from temporary files?)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not show what you do with `lc_2000_tiles`. Do you provide a `filename` argument? If not, the output goes to the temp folder, and perhaps this is on disk with not much space (and it is inefficient). You can set the temp folder with `terraOptions(tempdir = "....")`

Also, do you need `mosaic` or can you use `merge` (equivalent if you have non-overlapping areas)? If so, you can also use `vrt`:

```
v <- vrt(filelist_lc)
```

A "VRT" is a virtual raster. It can treat different files (typically adjacent non-overlapping tiles, but that is not required) as a single data source (file). With that, you could then do

```
x <- writeRaster(v, "combined.tif")
```

Comment: Ah, I did forget to specify a filename.

Comment: I've read a few things, but I don't really understand what a vrt is

Comment: I have added a sentence about it